# Why there is && after some function definitions in bash completion file?

Tags: bash, auto-completion

If you look at files `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/*` many have function definition followed by `&& complete -F` (at least in Xenial). Why is this?

Does the notation have some special meaning in bash completion file?

In bash, I don't see any functional difference between scripts

```
a(){ echo in;return 1;} && a
```

and

```
a(){ echo in;return 1;}; a
```

Comment: I have 809 files in that directory. Any particular example?

Comment: @muru Pick your favorite from the output of `grep -zE '}[[:space:]]+&&[[:space:]]+complete -F' /etc/bash_completion.d/*`

Comment: 82950 lines of output.

Comment: @muru Well, if you want particular, install ppa-purge and use that as an example.

Comment: @muru provided you are in Xenial or later.

Comment: @muru I think the other examples are for same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html#Shell-Functions) tells

> The exit status of a function definition is zero unless a syntax error occurs or a readonly function with the same name already exists. When executed, the exit status of a function is the exit status of the last command executed in the body.

Syntax error may terminate script execution before the `complete -F`command, so the command following the function declaration may not be executed anyway, but if a readonly function with same name is declared before sourcing the file containing the function, it may not terminate execution. To prevent a wrong bash completion function from being called, such a logical AND test is used.

Comment: I think it might be good to declare the functions made for bash completion readonly, so that the function - and thus the respective bash completion - could not changed afterwards.

Comment: Well, the function could be made readonly, but the completion can be changed with another `complete -F`, so there's not much point.

Answer (score 0):

`complete` is a **bash** builtin, which tells **bash** how to autocomplete in various situations. In particular, `complete -F` *funcname* *cmdname* tells **bash** that if the user has entered the command *cmdname* then the completion of the arguments is to be handled by the function *funcname*. Use `help complete` and `man bash` for further information. Many system-installed autocompletion files install autocompletion functions using the pattern

```
_cmd_name () {
  ... compute completions here and assign them to COMPREPLY ...
  return 0
} && complete -F _cmd_name cmd_name
```

For example,

```
_apt_get () {
  ... compute completions here and assign them to COMPREPLY ...
  return 0
} && complete -F _apt_get apt-get
```

which tells **bash** that if the user has type `apt-get` as the command name then the autocompletion will be handled by the function `_apt_get`.

It's purely a matter of coding style, and this style is not ugly or hard to understand.

Comment: I am used to understanding `&&` as  logical AND operator which is executed from left to right. So it feels awkward to me to use it after a function definition. Functions are executed only, if they are called.

Comment: `_func() { ... body ... ; } && complete -F _func _cmd` means `_func() { ... body ... } ;  [ "$(type -t _func 2>/dev/null)" = "function" ] && complete -F _func _cmd` but is shorter and easier on the eyes. A function definition _may fail_ just like anything else in this sublunar world.

Comment: I tested this and `_func() { ... body ... ; }; complete -F _func _cmd` seemed to work the same. If there were a syntax error in `func`, further commands were not sourced.

Comment: The equality you tell in your previous comment is not accurate; see my answer.